# Knockout JS removes extra space contained between two words while binding it to ko.grid

Tags: html, knockout-3.0

Could any of you please provide the solution that why knockout JS removes the extra space when I am binding to the grid.
For example, I am getting the below data for a column from the database.

```
"I am a  developer"
```

I have given two space between `"a`" and `"developer"` but when it binds with the grid, it removes the extra space and make it as `"I am a developer"`.

How can I preserve the spacing?

Comment: Please, post your html code, and your knockout model and the binding

Answer (score 1):

This is not a knockout problem, is about the way your HTML is displayed in the browser.

Your HTML renderer (browser itself) is taking those two spaces and combining then into one. Adding the empty HTML char code for white space (`&nbsp;`), **forces** the browser to display an empty space it.

Also, check this HTML tag `<pre></pre>` for *preformatted text* which renders the text *as is*. From the [W3C schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp):

> Text in a  element is displayed in a fixed-width font (usually
>   Courier), and it preserves both spaces and line breaks.